# Why is HashMap fail-fast just because it provides a means to iterate over its keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

**Here's what I know:**

---

- Fail-fast iterators will thrown a `ConcurrentModificationException`
  if I try to modify the given element while iterating through it,
  without the use of the iterator's methods (like `iterator.remove()`)
- It's not guaranteed that a fail-fast iterator will ALWAYS throw a CME.
- Fail-safe iterators won't throw CME.

---

I'm reading a book where I came across the following sentence:

> A HashMap provides its set of keys and a Java application can iterate
>   over them. Thus, a HashMap is fail-fast.

The part that I don't understand is where it says "Thus...". If someone would tell me that a HashMap provides its set of keys, I still wouldn't know whether it's a fail-fast or fail-safe (based on that alone).

**So why does, providing its own set of keys, make the HashMap fail-fast?**

**What's the connection between those two things**?

Comment: ".. can iterate over them".

Comment: The quote from the book is a non-sequitur. There is no requirement that maps' key sets provide fail-fast iterators. Also, `HashMap` isn't fail-fast, its *key/value/entry sets' iterators* are.

Comment: I agree. It is a *non sequitur.* Please provide a proper citation for the book so we can avoid it.

Comment: A [cursory Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22A+HashMap+provides+its+set+of+keys+and+a+Java+application+can+iterate+over+them%22) turns up a lot of instances of this exact quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually the first sentence which provides the information why HashMap's is fail-fast:

> A HashMap provides its set of keys and a Java application can iterate over them.

**Fail safe** iterators iterate over the private copy of the original collection, not the collection itself. Therefore any change to the original collection does not get noticed by the iterator, and hence it never throws **CME**.

Since `HashMap` provides **its** set of keys as in the quote above (rather than a copy of) it is therefore fail-fast.

Comment: @EJP with the quote now to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

The author just didn't complete the idea.

From javadocs of HashMap (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()):

*"Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations."*

The idea that wasn't expressed is that the hash map is iterated over using the keySet-provided Set (well, let's take that as iterating over the map...). As that set is fail-fast (as per the doc above), the map is also fail-fast.

Remember that other methods allow to iterate over the map (but luckily as far as I could see, they're also fail-fast). Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()

Answer (score 1):

Looking at internet pages that contain that exact sentence, I think the context was a comparison of `HashMap` with `HashTable`. It can be made clearer if you look at what the Javadoc says for `HashTable`:

> The iterators returned by the iterator method of the collections returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are *fail-fast*: if the Hashtable is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future. The Enumerations returned by Hashtable's keys and elements methods are *not* fail-fast.

So, armed with this background, we can figure out that the author of the HashMap vs HashTable comparison was trying to say that HashMap is fail-fast because it has a `keySet()` method, which returns fail-fast iterators as described by the above Javadoc. However, this gives incomplete information because it can be taken to imply that, unlike HashMap, HashTable isn't fail-fast. In fact, HashTable implements `Map` and therefore also has the `keySet()` method, so it also has fail-fast iterators just like HashMap. Another problem with that sentence is that it is misleading: it is not the HashMap that is fail-fast, but the iterators it returns.

Comment: correct! but now I don't understand why is hashtable's enum simply 'not fail-fast', instead of fail-safe?

Comment: @MarkoKitonjics I presume it's not fail-fast because it would require a change to its contract if it were allowed to throw ConcurrentModificationException, which would break backward compatibility, and it's not failsafe because it could affect performance as it would require a snapshot to be created when all you might want to do is just quickly enumerate the keys.